# Centos box locks up with irq error

Tags: centos6

Every couple months, network locks up and machine has to be manually rebooted.

Typically I just update the kernel & hope for the best.  But this seems to persist, albeit only a few times a year.  Are there any args I should be passing to kernel?

Running Centos 6.9.  Thanks in advance...

```
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: irq 63: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: Pid: 0, comm: swapper Tainted: G        W  -- ------------    2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: Call Trace:
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: <IRQ>  [<ffffffff810f583b>] ? __report_bad_irq+0x2b/0xa0
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff810f5a3c>] ? note_interrupt+0x18c/0x1d0
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81014b19>] ? read_tsc+0x9/0x10
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff810f6085>] ? handle_edge_irq+0xf5/0x180
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff8100fd29>] ? handle_irq+0x49/0xa0
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81552cac>] ? do_IRQ+0x6c/0xf0
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff8100ba53>] ? ret_from_intr+0x0/0x11
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: <EOI>  [<ffffffff81441b42>] ? poll_idle+0x42/0x90
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81441b1d>] ? poll_idle+0x1d/0x90
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81441d0a>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0x7a/0xe0
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81009fe6>] ? cpu_idle+0xb6/0x110
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff8152f22a>] ? rest_init+0x7a/0x80
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81c3b127>] ? start_kernel+0x429/0x436
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81c3a33a>] ? x86_64_start_reservations+0x125/0x129
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffff81c3a453>] ? x86_64_start_kernel+0x115/0x124
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: handlers:
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: [<ffffffffa0193ef0>] (e1000_msix_other+0x0/0x130 [e1000e])
Jun  1 07:51:26 search6 kernel: Disabling IRQ #63
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue originates from your network card (e1000_msix_other). You don't mention anything how the server is used.

Anyway, it could be that something in your network traffic triggers a bug in the network adapter / driver module, which then causes this issue.

This could be a new bug, and it would be useful to report this to intel-wired-lan@lists.osuosl.org, which is the mailing list for the driver.

If you want just simply to get rid of the error condition, try replacing your network adapter.